# How to Recover Data in LINUX MINT Quiana

Tags: linux, data-recovery

Can I recover deleted files in LINUX MINT 17 Quiana. I have deleted my folder containing data with shift+delete. Now, I want my data back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) that is powerful free data recovery software.
TestDisk has features for both novices and experts. For those who know little or nothing about data recovery techniques, TestDisk can be used to collect detailed information about a non-booting drive which can then be sent to a tech for further analysis. Those more familiar with such procedures should find TestDisk a handy tool in performing onsite recovery.